# Angular JS retrieve value from span

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can create a nice string from multiple input values:

```
<input ng-model="first">
<input ng-model="second">
<span ng-model="result">{{first}} and {{second}}</span>
```

How can I now retrieve the resulting string from JS? Ideally something like

```
var myResult = $scope.result
```

but I think I'm missing something...

Comment: {{first}} and {{second}} seems to be needed only for presentation purposes. Do you really need it as a model property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend doing something more like this:

**View**

```
<input ng-model="first">
<input ng-model="second">
<span>{{result}}</span>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.$watchCollection("[first,second]", function(newVals){
  $scope.result = newVals[0] + " and " + newVals[1];
});
```

Then you can use `var myResult = $scope.result`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiattp/y8WjA/2/). But just for a bit more context, `ngModel` is generally not used for binding to non-inputs. From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) (emphasis mine):

> The ngModel directive binds an **input,select, textarea (or custom form control)** to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

So depending on the end use-case you might want to create your own directive, but you might also want to ask yourself whether what you are trying to do is necessary, or whether there is a better way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! Only one remark, $watchCollection is not available in the current stable release.. but will hopefully be soon :)

Comment: Hmm yeah for now you could just use `$watch`... or upgrade to `1.1.4+` :).